# BluetoothSocket.connect() throws IOException

Tags: android, exception, io, bluetooth

My program connects with a embedded bluetooth device which acts as the server. I successfully find the nearby bluetooth devices, but when I try to connect to the new device, my program crashes due to an IO Exception when calling BluetoothSocket.connect(). I am having trouble figuring out what's going on so if someone could please help me out I'd really appreciate it.

I think it may have something to do with the UUID I randomly generate, but I'm not completely sure.

Thanks.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnScanDevice = (Button) findViewById( R.id.scandevice );

    stateBluetooth = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.bluetoothstate );
    startBluetooth();

    listDevicesFound = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.devicesfound );
    btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( AndroidBluetooth.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    listDevicesFound.setAdapter( btArrayAdapter );

    CheckBlueToothState();

    btnScanDevice.setOnClickListener( btnScanDeviceOnClickListener );

    registerReceiver( ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND ) );

    listDevicesFound.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
    {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
      {
          myBtDevice = btDevicesFound.get( arg2 );
          try {
              btSocket = myBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( MY_UUID );
              iStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
              oStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
          } catch ( IOException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Bluetooth not available, or insufficient permissions" );
          } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer One" );
          }
          myBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
          CheckBlueToothState();
          try {
              btSocket.connect();
          } catch ( IOException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "IO Exception" );
          } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer Two" );
          }
      } 

  });
}

private void CheckBlueToothState() {
    if( myBtAdapter == null ) {
        stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth NOT supported" );
    } else {
        if( myBtAdapter.isEnabled() ) {
            if( myBtAdapter.isDiscovering() ) {
                stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is currently " +
                        "in device discovery process." );
            } else {
                stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is Enabled." );
                btnScanDevice.setEnabled( true );
            }
        } else {
            stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is NOT enabled" );
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE );
            startActivityForResult( enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT );
        }
    }
}

private Button.OnClickListener btnScanDeviceOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View arg0 ) {
        btArrayAdapter.clear();
        myBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
};


@Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    if( requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT ) {
        CheckBlueToothState();
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals( action ) ) {
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra( BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE );
            btDevicesFound.add( btDevice );
            btArrayAdapter.add( btDevice.getName() + "\n" + btDevice.getAddress() );
            btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }           
    }
};
public static void startBluetooth(){
    try {
        myBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        myBtAdapter.enable();
    } catch ( NullPointerException ex ) {
        Log.e( "Bluetooth", "Device not available" );
    }
}

public static void stopBluetooth() {
    myBtAdapter.disable();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with the code you have posted, though only one is related to your crash.

Most likely your crash in logcat says something like "Command rejected".  The UUID is a value that must point to a published service on your embedded device, **it can't just be randomly generated**.  In other words, the RFCOMM SPP connection you want to access has a specific UUID that it publishes to identify that service, and when you create a socket it must use the matching UUID.

[This blog post I wrote](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/11/android-bluetooth-rfcomm/) may assist you in how you can query your device to get the proper UUID that needs to be inserted into your program.  Prior to Android 4.0 the SDK pretty much assumed you knew it ahead of time (you obtained it from the Bluetooth OEM, etc.) so discovering it from your device it a bit roundabout.  If you are lucky enough to have a 4.0.3 device, `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` and `getUuids()` are now public methods you can call them directly to find all the published services and their associated UUID values.

The second issue with your code that will probably hit you later is that you cannot obtain the data streams from your socket until after you have connected, so you'll probably need to rewrite your method more like this:

```
      myBtDevice = btDevicesFound.get( arg2 );
      try {
          btSocket = myBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( MY_UUID );
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
          Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Bluetooth not available, or insufficient permissions" );
      }

      myBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
      CheckBlueToothState();
      try {
          btSocket.connect();
          //Get streams after connect() returns without error
          iStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
          oStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
          Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "IO Exception" );
      } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
          Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer Two" );
      }
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I am working with Android 2.0 for this application. I originally thought it would be a specific UUID, but couldn't find it anywhere. If you know where to look, or how to look, I would appreciate it a lot. The application runs on a Lenovo Ideapad A1, and it is attempting to connect to an embedded RN-41 bluetooth chip. It also does not connect to only one chip, it should have the capability to connect to several different chips ( not at the same time, but you can disconnect from one and the find another ). thanks again

Comment: So...read the blog post and it will tell you ways to do it on 2.0

Comment: Haha sorry I posted that before clicking the link, but I have been reading it. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If you look at this again, I'm still stuck. I really am not comfortable with the structuring of android yet, and don't know where to put the code given on your website. I asked another question if you're willing to go take a look.

Comment: Hello @devunwired 
I am having a RN4870 device, and I am trying to connect it using createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() method, but I am getting "java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1" everytime, and it is not connecting. 

Also, I want to Read/Write data using Transparent UART. Can you help me out in this ?